# Не выводит информацию из бд в view. ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Использую sql management studio 2016

***Вот скрин:***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Код в View ( Index.cshtml):**

```html
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Book>
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div>
    <h3>Распродажа книг</h3>
    <table>
        <tr class="header">
            <td><p>Название книги</p></td>
            <td><p>Автор</p></td>
            <td><p>Цена</p></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        @foreach (WebApplication1.Models.Book b in Model)
            {
            <tr>
                <td><p>@b.Name</p></td>
                <td><p>@b.Author</p></td>
                <td><p>@b.Price</p></td>
                <td><p><a href="/Home/Buy/@b.Id">Купить</a></p></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

**WebConfig:**

```html
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BookContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|\Bookstore.mdf';Integrated Security=True"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

**HomeController:**

```
   BookContext db = new BookContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Books);
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

**BookContext:**

```
 public class BookContext : DbContext
{
    public BookContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    { }
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }

}
```

**В Бд есть данные:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Возможно дело в том, что после запуска база данных выключена ? :*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поменяйте `public BookContext() : base("DefaultConnection")` на `public BookContext() : base("name=BookContext") { }`

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk Спасибо! :)

Comment: @AnrewRomanuk, заработало ?

Comment: Да. Можете ответить, я выберу лучший ответ ваш.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поменяйте название подключения согласно файлу `Web.config`

```
public BookContext() : base("name=BookContext") { }
```

Answer (score -2):

Передай объекты в `ViewBag`

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // создаем контекст данных
        BookContext db = new BookContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            // получаем из бд все объекты Book
            IEnumerable<Book> books = db.Books;
            // передаем все объекты в динамическое свойство Books в ViewBag
            ViewBag.Books = books;
            // возвращаем представление
            return View();
        }
    }
```

А потом выводи на странице

```
@foreach (var b in ViewBag.Books)
        {
        <tr>
            <td><p>@b.Name</p></td>
            <td><p>@b.Author</p></td>
            <td><p>@b.Price</p></td>
            <td><p><a href="/Home/Buy/@b.Id">Купить</a></p></td>
        </tr>
        }
```

И еще у тебя должен быть класс Book

```
public class Book
{
    // ID книги
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // название книги
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // автор книги
    public string Author { get; set; }
    // цена
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Эх, все равно не работает (